# JSP - Allow user to download files from server

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have written a program in Java/JSP which dynamically creates a CSV file based on user input and stores it (on the server).

How can I allow the user to download this file?

Currently using the following to decide the path to store the file.

```
String csv2 = "D:\\erp\\Dispatch\\DC_" + (df.format(date)).toString() + "_Print.csv";
CSVWriter writer2 = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv2));
```

According to my research, the best bet is to store it in the web-directory and provide the relative path to the file. In that case, where should I store the file (or how should I store it to the web-directory)?

*NOTE: The above path is being set in the JSP, and hence I can use the same variables to provide the URL/path to the users*

*NOTE 2: Server is a tomcat server*

Comment: Do you really want a file on the server, or do you want the user to download dynamically generated CSV, just like it downloads dynamically generated HTML when going to your servlet or JSP? If the latter, write the CSV to the response writer, rather then to a FileWriter. If the former, then read the file and write it to the response writer. Don't put the file under the webapp folder.

Comment: Hey thanks. Any link or something that might help in understanding how should I work with response writer?

Comment: No. But it's a Writer, and you can use it like any other Writer: you write chars to it, and these chars constitute the response body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a file and -without storing it on the server- return it immediately as a downloadable file to the client.

This has the advantage that you don't need temporary storage on your server that might grow and keep growing unless you regularly clean it out.

Ofcourse if you wish to create an "archive" of old CSV files as a service to your clients then this is no real advantage. But most of the time the 'create/offer-for-download/throw-away' is the more interesting approach.

Here's some example code that may give you some idea:

1) the servlet (note: exception handling not shown)

```
public class CsvDownloadServlet extends HttpServlet
{
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException
{
    // fetch parameters from HTTP request

    String param = (String)request.getParameter("p");
    if (param == null)
    {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Parameter p missing");
        return;
    }

    .... perhaps fetch more parameters ....

    .... build your CSV, using the parameter values ....

    String result = .... // suppose result is your generated CSV contents
    String filename = .... // choose a file name that your browser will suggest when saving the download

    // prepare writing the result to the client as a "downloadable" file

    response.setContentType("text/csv");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+filename+"\"");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "-1");

    // actually send result bytes
    response.getOutputStream().write(result.getBytes());
}
}
```

2) configuration in WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0"> 
     ....
    <servlet>
        <display-name>download</display-name>
        <servlet-name>download</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mypackage.CsvDownloadServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>download</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/download</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    ....
</web-app>
```

3) the link on your page to trigger the download:

```
<a href="/myapp/download?p=myparamvalue">Click Here</a>
```

Here, `/myapp` is the "context-root" of your application, `/download` is configured in `web.xml` to be the location that triggers the `CsvDownloadServlet` code. `p` is an example parameter (see servlet code).
If you have a form where the user fills in the parameter values, it could look like this:

```
 <form method='GET' action='/myapp/download'>
    Enter a value for parameter "p":
    <input id="p" type="text" size="10" name="p">
    <input type="submit" value="Generate and Download">
 </form>
```

This has the same effect as the previous `<a>` link, only the parameters are user supplied. As soon as the user clicks the submit button, the servlet code will be invoked and the CSV generation and subsequent download will start.
Again, user input checking is not shown.

Comment: Thanks bro. I've already solved this issue (fgot to close). Yours seems to be a more comprehensive way though :)

Answer (score -4):

Use this code:

```
<a href="path for the file" download="filename with extension"><u>Download</u></a>
```